# Fuzzy and blurred display of drop-down menus in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, radeon, ubuntu-gnome, menu

I have recently migrated from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 in my PC with AMD Radeon video. Drop-down menus appear to be fuzzy and blurred. Please refer to the screen-shot attached. I did a lot of online searches and also tried tweaking font-hinting and antialiasing but of no avail.

This problem had not occurred when I used Ubuntu 16.04. My installation of Ubuntu 18.04 was clean. Please help, regards.

[Fuzzy menu appearing on placing mouse pointer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D2nj.png)

Comment: I suspect you GPU is radeon?  (is it?) If so it's likely you're suffering from this bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/fedora/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/1841718) which is in -proposed currently.

Comment: @guiverc , yes my GPU is indeed AMD Radeon, thanks for information that its a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be fixed now. Thanks to the community for fixing this bug. Special thanks to [guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/users/469152/guiverc) for informing me about this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/fedora/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/1841718).